# How to add "lwIP library" to Eclipse XSDK Zynq Application Project?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, lwip, xsdk

How to add "lwIP library" to Eclipse XSDK Zynq Application Project?

I tried following the instructions in "Xilinx Standalone Library
Documentation" for Zynq-7000 CPU under the chapter for "lwIP" library.

So basically, I create a FreeRTOS application project

Then the instructions say open the "The Board Support Package Settings window"... which I can't find... and then:

```
(e) Select the lwip202 library with version 1_1 .
On the left side of the SDK window, lwip202_v1_1 appears in the list of libraries to be compiled.
(f) Select lwip202 in the Project Explorer view.
The configuration options for lwIP are listed.
(g) Configure the lwIP and click OK.
The board support package automatically builds with lwIP included in it.
```

How to find the BSP settings windows in XSDK?

Answer (score 0):

How to adding lwIP library to XSDK project.

1. Create Application project named  with FreeRTOS option selected.
2. Right click _bsp and select "Board Support Package Settings"
3. Click Check box "lwip"
4. click ok.